# How to create a custom index in Filebeat/Metric beat

Tags: elastic-stack, filebeat, elk, metricbeat, elastic-cloud

Requirement is to create a custom index in filebeat. Which is running as a daemonset in Kubernetes. I need logs of different namespace to have separate index. Is there any way to implement this as filebeat does not provide flexibility like log stash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved this issue by using below in filbeat.yml

Go to filebeat.tml file then make this change(assuming u have provided Kubernetes meta data as input in filebeat.yml

[image: Use this in filebeat.yml file]
Once u do this restart filbeat then next create index pattern this should be listed when u created an index pattern. Create the index pattern and check the logs it worked for me.